# Odata response length

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, odata

I was looking at some places and was not able to find details, about the OData message length. 
When the response is to long the message is chunked and the last message contains the link to the next response part. I am wondering if there is an ability to increase the size of the single response length and what is the limitation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about server driven paging? You can control the number of entities in a page by using PageSize property on the QueryableAttribute. More about that in [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging) official tutorial.